# Timer.Elapsed handler abruptly stops

Tags: c#, xamarin, timer, xamarin.android

```
var checkTimer = new Timer();
checkTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
    bool? doneIndexing = serviceConnection.GetIndexStatus();                    
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Indexing status: {doneIndexing}");
    if (doneIndexing.HasValue && doneIndexing == true)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Done indexing, updating UI");
        var indexStatusView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.indexStatusView);
        var indexProgress = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.indexProgress);
        indexStatusView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.done_indexing);
        indexProgress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        checkTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
};
checkTimer.Interval = 100;
checkTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Execution stops at `indexStatusView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.done_indexing)`. It does get called a few times more when `doneIndexing == true`, but even if I move the disable line to the top, execution still stops at that same line. What could cause this?

Comment: you are in a different thread then the ui thread?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Apparently this timer is usually on another thread. Or even several different Threads. This is not a timer for people without knowledge of Multithreading.

Comment: @Christopher yeaeh well - and in C# with WPF you get big problems if you try to access stuff in the UI-Thread from outside of it, because you want to change it - it might be ("might" - no xamarin experience here) that when the thing stops working when cross-threadeadly accessing `indexStatusView.Text` - **an UI component**, the reasons are the same. Like, for example getting an Exception because of cross-thread UI access ... good that you have some knowledge of MT :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner As teh elapsed even swallows all Exceptions, it could be just about anything happening in there. CrossThreading is not even the worst possible Exception. I am mostly worried about Fatal ones being swallowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Execution stops at indexStatusView.Text .....

Perform your UI updates on the UI thread, ie:

```
if (doneIndexing.HasValue && doneIndexing == true)
{
    var indexStatusView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.indexStatusView);
    var indexProgress = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.indexProgress);
    Log.Debug(TAG, "Done indexing, updating UI");
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        indexStatusView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.done_indexing);
        indexProgress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    });
    checkTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: no xamarin here, only wpf. whats the diff between `InvokeOnMainThread`  and `RunOnUiThread` ? Ah,saw your commont on mine and deleted :)

Comment: The problem is the same ;) what I googled up was for iOs

Comment: He is coding C# via `Xamarin.Android`, no WPF here.

Comment: Read the comments below the question :) it is a cross thread UI access problem that exists for C# WPF as well - where I do most my coding. which lead me to googleing `xamarin ui thread cross` and led me erroneously to InvokeOnMainThread.

Answer (score -3):

I just looked up this timer and my best guess is that you have an Exception that is swallwoed. Apparently this Timer uses heavy Multithreading. It is even possible for multiple Elapsed Events to run in parlell on different pool threads.

Unfortuantley Multithreading is notriously good at swallowing Exceptions. And this one seems to have no abiltiy to avoid this or expose the Exceptions: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed/

"If the Timer.SynchronizingObject property is null, the Timer.Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If the processing of the Timer.Elapsed event lasts longer than Timer.Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant."

"The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Timer.Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework."

Your abiltiy to debug it depends on your skills on getting Exceptions out of alterante Threads and possibly general multithreading. Considering the possibly long running nature of this work, maybe a Rate Limitation would be better? Run code like this in another Thread:

```
integer interval = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```